# Camunda Optimize cannot be started. Port already in used

Tags: spring, spring-boot, camunda, camunda-modeler

As I'm trying to exploit the Camunda Enterprise version, now I'm stuck at the Optimize server. I'm not able to start the Optimize server followed by instruction. Here is the log file

```
16:59:37.322 [main] DEBUG o.e.j.u.component.AbstractLifeCycle - starting ServerConnector@48974e45{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8095}
16:59:37.325 [main] WARN  o.e.j.u.component.AbstractLifeCycle - FAILED ServerConnector@48974e45{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8095}: java.io.IOException: Failed to bind to /0.0.0.0:8095
java.io.IOException: Failed to bind to /0.0.0.0:8095
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.openAcceptChannel(ServerConnector.java:346)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.open(ServerConnector.java:307)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractNetworkConnector.doStart(AbstractNetworkConnector.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.doStart(ServerConnector.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:385)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:72)
    at org.camunda.optimize.jetty.EmbeddedCamundaOptimize.startOptimize(EmbeddedCamundaOptimize.java:169)
    at org.camunda.optimize.Main.main(Main.java:17)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.openAcceptChannel(ServerConnector.java:342)
    ... 8 common frames omitted
```

I know it is obvious but I tried to changing different port. It's still showing the same error, no matter which port I choose. Please help to take a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The port is already in use, the message is obvious. All you can do is to kill the process that is listening to this thread.

I use Windows, but you can search for Linux way to do, the principle is the same.

**Windows**:

1. Find a process that uses the port 8095 using `netstat -aon | find "8095"`. The result looks like:

   ```
   TCP    0.0.0.0:8003           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       23332
   TCP    [::]:8003              [::]:0                 LISTENING       23332
   ```
2. Find in the Task Manager in the Details tab what runs under the PID (process ID) number `23332`.
3. End such a task. It will be probably `java.exe` since there is a pending process listening to the port. Restart the IDE and everything should work well. If it is ex. a database or anything else, you have to use a different port than 8095 either at your side or the application that already uses it.

**Linux:** https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/140482/kill-any-service-running-at-a-specific-port

Comment: Silly me. Thanks for your feedback. I'm able to resolve the "Address already in use: bind" but the Camunda Optimize still cannot be started with no error :(

Comment: Don't hesitate to open another question and leave this one since "Port already in used" seems to be resolved. There is an error elsewhere for sure. Don't forget to try to investigate first and provide the logs. Moreover, there is surely something logged in the text log as well.

Comment: Thanks @Nikolas. Let me investigate further.